# Running a Docker Container on AWS ELB, connected to the host Node app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What I'm trying to do is twofold: one, run a Docker container (preferably created from a Dockerfile, rather than pulled from an image) on my Elastic Beanstalk environment, which already has running a Node application in production. Then, connect the two together, so that my server (running on the Docker container) will be accessible via localhost on the host machine. The end goal of this is to allow the two to communicate via TCP, but I have that figured out sans Dockeriziation.

From what I've seen, AWS has an option for single-container Docker apps; however, it's unclear to me whether it's intended for apps solely running on Docker, or a scenario like mine. From what I've read, I'm leaning towards the former.

Therefore, is my only option to manually install Docker as a package on my instances, run it as a service, and build and run from the Dockerfile that way? It seems rather roundabout, and I believe I've tried it before with limited success - but if that's the road that is best, that's what I'll try!

Thanks for any help you guys can give me. Will accept the first answer that gives a feasible solution.

Comment: Why do you want to connect from host machine to the container over TCP?

Comment: This depends on few things. Is the Node app always going to be run on a single EC2 instance? Would be be horizontally scaling the app? If yes then why would you use localhost to reach this dockerized service, you are creating a unnecessary tieup between the two.

Comment: The answer is a pretty simple one - I'm using this container to perform a very specific task in Python, one I can't do in Node. There will be more than one instance, but it's perfectly fine if each instance has it's own container for this function. Eventually, we plan to move to a fully multi-container setup, one which will allow us to link the main application and this container together in a more traditional manner. But until then, we need a way to bridge the two so they can communicate, and TCP seems easiest.

Comment: That being said, I'm not as much worried about that, I'm pretty sure simply exposing the ports will take care of the communication side of things. Maybe not. But I'm much more bothered by the actual installation process.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you will want to package you existing Node app in a Docker container and then run both apps in containers using the [ELB Multi Container Docker environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html).

You will need to store both Containers in either a private or public registry.  To leverage the AWS Registry service follow the instructions from [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html) article.  You then reference your containers in the Dockerrun.aws.json file for your EB environment.

To allow the containers to communicate with each other, include "links" to your other containers in the Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "my-node-app",
      "image": "registry:my-node-app",
      "essential": true,
    {
      "name": "other-container",
      "image": "registry:other-container",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "my-node-app"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case Docker exposes your node container to your other container via the hostname "my-node-app" (this is an abbreviated Dockerrun file just fyi)

Comment: That is the long-term plan. But it's infeasible to make that switch today. This is an intermediate step until then.

Comment: So you want to spin up the Docker container on your EB host outside of the automated deployment?  To do that you would need to would need to define it in an .ebextensions file. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html